# Trying to redirect from non SSL certificated sites to SSL certificated sites

Tags: apache, redirect, ssl-certificate

I bought a SSL certificate for the domain *https://www.mypage.com*. I have other domains like *https://www.mypage.fr*, *https://www.mypage.es*...For those I didn't buy a SSL certificate.

When I go to *https://www.mypage.com* the page is showed directly OK, but if I go to *https://www.mypage.fr*, the browser shows the typical message "This Connection is Untrusted"..

When the user enter to *https://www.mypage.fr* I would like to redirect the user to *https://www.mypage.com* in order to not showing the message "This connection is untrusted..".

For that, I have written this in my .htaccess:

```
RewriteCond %{SERVER_PORT} ^443$
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www.mypage.com [NC] 
RewriteRule (.*)$ https://www.mypage.com [R=301,L]
```

but when I go to *https://www.mypage.fr* the browser still shows the message "This connection is untrusted...".

So what should I do to redirect my sites avoiding this message?

Regards

Javi

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't prevent it.  Before your server gets any control over what's happening, the browser checks the certificate and issues the warning.

Is there any reason the user would be going to `https://www.mypage.fr` rather than `http://www.mypage.fr`?  You can redirect from `http://www.mypage.fr` to `https://www.mypage.com` without any warnings.